# I need help on how to implement class that can be shown in object Inspector

Tags: delphi, class, object, properties, custom-component

i have

```
...
  TDispPitch = class
  private
    iLineSize: Integer;
    iLineColor: TColor;
    bDisplayAccent: Boolean;
    bVisible: Boolean;
  published
    property LineSize : Integer read iLineSize write iLineSize;
    ...etc
  end;
...
```

and i wanted this feature shown in Object Insepector to edit the settings.

i try adding

```
property DispPitch: TDispPitch read FDispPitch write FDispPitch. like
```

the DispPitch can be shown but i cannot see its properties. like LineSize, LineColor etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must derive your class from `TPersistent`, or a descendant, in order to make it available in the Object Inspector:

```
TDispPitch = class(TPersistent)
private
  ...
published
  property ...
  ...
end;
```

From Delphi Documentation:

> TPersistent is the ancestor for all
>   objects that have assignment and
>   streaming capabilities.

Comment: You also need to override the `TPersistent.Assign()` method, and then have the containing class's property use a setter method that calls Assign() insted of assigns its field pointer directly.  See my other answer.

Answer (score 3):

The class needs to derive from `TPersistent`, and should implement the Assign() (or AssignTo()) method, as well as expose an `OnChange` event so the containing class can react to changes, eg:

```
type
  TDispPitch = class(TPersistent)
  private 
    iLineSize: Integer; 
    iLineColor: TColor; 
    bDisplayAccent: Boolean; 
    bVisible: Boolean; 
    FOnChange: TNotifyEvent;
    procedure Changed;
    procedure SetLineSize(Value : Integer); 
    procedure SetLineColor(Value: TColor); 
    procedure SetDisplayAccent(Value: Boolean); 
    procedure SetVisible(Value: Boolean); 
  public
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
    property OnChange: TNotifyEvent read FOnChange write FOnChange;
  published 
    property LineSize : Integer read iLineSize write SetLineSize; 
    property LineColor: TColor read iLineColor write SetLineColor; 
    property DisplayAccent: Boolean read bDisplayAccent write SetDisplayAccent; 
    property Visible: Boolean read bVisible write SetVisible; 
  end; 

procedure TDispPitch.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
var
  LSource: TDispPitch;
begin
  if Source is TDispPitch then
  begin
    LSource := TDispPitch(Source);
    iLineSize := LSource.LineSize;
    iLineColor := LSource.LineColor; 
    bDisplayAccent := LSource.DisplayAccent; 
    bVisible := LSource.Visible; 
    Changed;
  end else
    inherited;
end;

procedure TDispPitch.Changed;
begin
  if FOnChange <> nil then FOnChange(Self);
end;

procedure TDispPitch.SetLineSize(Value : Integer);
begin
  if iLineSize <> Value then
  begin
    iLineSize := Value;
    Changed;
  end;
end;

procedure TDispPitch.SetLineColor(Value: TColor); 
begin
  if iLineColor <> Value then
  begin
    iLineColor := Value;
    Changed;
  end;
end;

procedure TDispPitch.SetDisplayAccent(Value: Boolean); 
begin
  if bDisplayAccent <> Value then
  begin
    bDisplayAccent := Value;
    Changed;
  end;
end;

procedure TDispPitch.SetVisible(Value: Boolean); 
begin
  if bVisible <> Value then
  begin
    bVisible := Value;
    Changed;
  end;
end;
```

Then you use it like this:

```
type
  TSomeOtherClass = class(...)
  private
    FDispPitch: TDispPitch;
    procedure DispPitchChanged(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SetDispPitch(Value: TDispPitch);
  public
    constructor Create; override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property DispPitch: TDispPitch read FDispPitch write SetDispPitch;
  end;

constructor TSomeOtherClass.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FDispPitch := TDispPitch.Create;
end;

destructor TSomeOtherClass.Destroy;
begin
  FDispPitch.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TSomeOtherClass.DispPitchChanged(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ... use new FDispPitch values as needed...
end;

procedure TSomeOtherClass.SetDispPitch(Value: TDispPitch);
begin
  FDispPitch.Assign(Value);
end;
```