# What is the correct code to override Assign method?

Tags: delphi

I'm confused by the Assign code in many other threads, for example, this one:
[See the Assign method implementation given in an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084965/i-need-help-on-how-to-implement-class-that-can-be-shown-in-object-inspector).

```
procedure TDispPitch.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
var
  LSource: TDispPitch;
begin
  if Source is TDispPitch then
  begin
    LSource := TDispPitch(Source);
    iLineSize := LSource.LineSize;
    iLineColor := LSource.LineColor; 
    bDisplayAccent := LSource.DisplayAccent; 
    bVisible := LSource.Visible; 
    Changed;
  end else
    inherited;
end;
```

But if the call to inherited is in the Else part, how are the base class properties assigned for an object that satisfies the if condition? Compare this to the VCL's own code for TStringList.

```
procedure TStringList.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
begin
  inherited Assign(Source);
  if Source is TStringList then
  begin
    FCaseSensitive := TStringList(Source).FCaseSensitive;
    ...
  end;
end;
```

This correctly calls Inherited first so that base class properties are assigned first.

So is the first code block right? I find such a code at many places on stack overflow. I can't understand how the base class properties are assigned in that code. Can someone explain? On the other hand, if the code is wrong, why hasn't someone pointed it out in all those threads?

Comment: It depends on whether there are any base class properties. Impossible to judge the first code sample removed from its context. You clearly have a perfect understanding of how all the parts work. I'm sure you can evaluate the code yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. I want to understand it from a best practice point of view. I think the VCL code above is always going to work. What I don't understand is the use of "else" in the first code. What is the harm in always calling inherited first? I think I need to understand how the streaming system uses it. All the code examples that talk about TCollectionItem and TOwnedCollection based classes use that kind of code.

Comment: The else is to channel execution to `TPersistent.Assign` which calls `Source.AssignTo(Self)` and gives the `Source` instance an opportunity to implement the assign action. This provides a mechanism for one class to, in effect, implement an `Assign` in another class without modifying that other class. I'm sure you can understand this if you just read the source. You understand what `inherited` means.

Comment: Let me put the question in another way. When I'm deriving a component from another component, isn't the 2nd form of coding safest? I know what properties I added in the derived component. I can code that without looking at the source of the base which seems like a redundant thing to me. Why isn't that form a standard then just like the constructor where everyone calls inherited first and then sets the new property values?

Comment: Nope, that's not the case at all. The call to the inherited `Assign` in `TStringList.Assign` calls `TStrings.Assign`, which typically won't call `TPersistent.Assign`. If you are implementing an `Assign` method in your class, you typically don't want to call `TPersistent.Assign` unless the `Source` object type is not recognised. Why are you so reluctant to read the RTL source code? Wouldn't it be easier and more effective for you to read it, than for us to read it and explain it to you?

Comment: But let's be clear about the two blocks of code in the question. They are both correct. They differ because of the different heritage of the classes. There is no one size fits all solution here. If you take the time to understand why these two `Assign` implementations differ, by reading the source, code, you will be able to make correct decisions when writing your own code.

Comment: "Why are you so reluctant to read the RTL source code?" I don't have time to get into that kind of detail. That's why I asked it on SO because I think there are experts here who might give me some hints. I did spend some time looking at the samples of the Assign in various places. All I want is a set of rules that helps me decide which of the above I want to code.

Comment: I'll help you when I get some time

Comment: @user173399 You should consider investing the time to do all possible research, including reading the source code if available. Please see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: But I'm now using a Starter edition and that doesn't have source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got around to solving this. Actually, when I went to implement a Sort on the TCollection, it didn't work and then finally I was able to see what was wrong and how it should work. I had to look at the sources in my old Delphi XE4 version to confirm my finding.

Here are the important points to consider when writing the overridden Assign code:

- The Assign in TPersistent does nothing. In fact, it catches the error if a derived class didn't implement the Assign override at the time it is needed. It shows a message that says something like "Can not assign."
- So if you have derived a class straight from TPersistent, you need the code like the first example at the top. The call to Inherited doesn't really achieve anything because the real work of assigning is done by the upper If block. My collection item had the code in the second example even though it was deriving from TCollectionItem which is a TPersistent class with no Assign logic of its own. Hence, the call to Inherited which occurred first was immediately causing an exception "Can not assign" as soon as the sort tried to exchange items.
- Taking this further, if your class is derived from an intermediate class based on TPersistent, you need to know if it has its own Assign logic. If yes, you must use the second example at the top so that the inherited Assign logic gets a chance to do its magic first. In my case, I had a class derived from TOwnedCollection/TCollection with its own Assign logic that copies the Items from one collection to another. So I had to use the second example at the top.

Let's try to summarize what we learned from the point of view of using TCollectionItem and TCollection/TOwnedCollection:

**Assign of the class that has the ancestor TOwnedCollection/TCollection:** Use the second example code block at the top so that the collection can do its assigns before yours.

**Assign of the class that has the ancestor TCollectionItem/TPersistent:** Use the first example code block at the top because both of these do not have their own Assigns. However, if you are deriving from another class based on these and it has its own Assign logic, you must use the second example so that its Assign executes first by the call to Inherited.